# Label cannot be fully displayed in bar chart

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart

The bar chart I currently have can be found here https://ibb.co/mcrdV8R. The problem is, because some of the labels on the y-axis are relatively long, they are truncated to the left. Is there a way to display them in full (eg. shrink the bar chart part, etc) because I cannot make the labels shorter. In addition, how to make the bars thinner? Thanks in advance!

```
plt.barh(posBP, -np.log10(p_BP), color='#FF8000')
plt.barh(posMF, -np.log10(p_MF), color='#FF3333')
plt.barh(posCC, -np.log10(p_CC), color='#FFB266')
plt.yticks(np.arange(len(BP)+len(MF)+len(CC)),des_CC[::-1]+des_MF[::-1]+des_BP[::-1])
plt.xlabel('-$\log_{10}(p\_value)$')
```

Comment: Can't you add a 'line feed' ('\n') to your labels?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can adjust your `barh` container thickness with the `width` argument manually and simply use matplotlib function [tight_layout()](https://matplotlib.org/users/tight_layout_guide.html)  which automatically adjusts the figure area :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# random data
x = np.arange(1,13,1)
y = np.random.random(len(x))
# Adjust width of your bars here
width = 0.1

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(11.69,8.27))
ax.barh(x, y, width, color='r') 
ax.set_xlabel('-$\log_{10}(p\_value)$')
ax.set_title('GO terms, Genes biased towards Nsyl in Root')
ax.set_yticks(x)   # set the position of the y ticks
ax.set_yticklabels(('5-triphosphate 6-kinase thingy which is important to know','other tick','and so on...'))
# matplotlib automatically adjusts the layout
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

which gives :

[image]

Comment: Nice! Thanks for the tip